# Easist way to export Google Spreadsheet API to my PHP site?

Tags: php, web

I am using my vaccation to test some new features for web programming.
I felt over the Google Spreadsheet API.

And was told it was possible to get "print" on a website with it?

I'm trying to figure out how to, get for instance (3,3) = the link qer.dk
Printed out to a HTML/PHP file?

Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Au2byfLzGSxddHExRzYtNUFVWDlWa0VHQ3NGdTNiS2c&output=html

What code line would I have to put into my HTML?
Does somebody got a link for a tutorial regarding the Spreadsheet & Web coding i seem to found nothing :/

Best regards